# Enable ScrollView over scroll in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've implemented a vertical scroll view (using `List`) containing two horizontal scroll views (using `ScrollView`s). The UI currently looks like this:

[image]

Here's the relevant code I've written to produce above UI:

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            CategoryRow(...)
            CategoryRow(...)
            Spacer()
        }
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Featured"))
    }
}
```

Inside each `CategoryRow`, there's an `HStack` embedded inside a `ScrollView`.
When introducing a padding on the left & right edges, I get this result:

[image]

As you can see, as a result of the padding, the horizontal scroll views are cut-off.

### Question

Is there a way to have the horizontal scroll views over-scroll past their boundaries?
The result I am looking for is that there is padding on the left of the scroll views when the scroll offset is 0 and padding on the right when the scrolling all the way to the right.

In UIKit, I did this by setting the contentOffset of the collection view...

Comment: I am not sure it is clear for me what the result do you expect. Do you won't to automatically scroll to some item onAppear?

Comment: Remove the padding from the right side

Comment: @DenFav I've updated my post. Does that make any sense?

Comment: @jsbeginnerNodeJS If I remove the padding on the right and scroll all the way to the right, the last item will have no padding on the right, but be on the border of the screen directly.

Comment: What about adding padding on the right side in the row itself.

Comment: That's a workaround I've been using so far, but it's not really the ideal way to go. Thanks for the suggestion. @jsbeginnerNodeJS

Comment: Why it's not ideal? That's how it works

Comment: In UIKit, I could specify an offset for the scrollView's content view by setting the respective constraints. *That* is ideal.

Comment: If you're not statisfied you can still use the standard uiscrollview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the `padding` modifier to your HStack inside the RowView

```
.padding(.horizontal, 20)
```